# Accessing persistent H2 DB in docker container

Tags: spring-boot, docker, containers

I'm deploying a springboot application and I want to use a persistent DB. So, in application.properties file, I have

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:/home/ubuntu/db;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;
```

Now this works as long as I start this application without using a container. Now, I build a docker image and try to run the application. Dockerfile looks like

```
FROM maven:3-jdk-11 AS maven
ARG BUILD = target/build.jar
COPY ${BUILD} build.jar
EXPOSE 8080
USER spring:spring
ENTRYPOINT["java","-jar","/build.jar"]
```

Now this doesn't work when I try to start it, because it searches for /home/ubuntu/db inside the container, which does not exist. Is there a way to make the app inside the docker container access the host folder /home/ubuntu/db? Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing part is to tell docker when running the containter to mount `/home/ubuntu/db` from the host into the container.

You do that like this:
`docker run -v <folder_on_host>:<folder_in_cointainer>`

with your example:
`docker run -v /home/ubuntu/db:/home/ubuntu/db`

more info on docker docs: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/06_bind_mounts/

Comment: Thanks, it seems this is the standard way, but when I run ```docker run -v /home/ubuntu/db:/home/ubuntu/db``` , I get a Java fileNotFoundException.

Comment: This comes from your java application. Ensure the directory exists on your host. Maybe permissions are involved.
This could be also related to something else, the stacktrace is usually very important to narrow down the root cause of an exception.

Comment: Ok, I solved the issue finally, but it didn't have to be so hard, I couldn't find this problem documented extensively anywhere. So when the folder from the host machine is mounted on the container, the container by default does not have permission to edit this folder. Hence, we need to use --privileged flag with docker run.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case it is helpful to anyone else, the full command to be used is:

```
docker run -v /home/ubuntu/db:/home/ubuntu/db --privileged -p $HOST_PORT:$CONTAINER_PORT <image-name>
```